# Apache Camel: CXF - returning Holder values (error: IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1)

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I have a problem with setting holders in my output message.
I have following simple routing and processor:

```
from("cxf:bean:ewidencjaEndpoint")
    .process(new ProcessResult())
    .end();

public class ProcessResult implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        Object[] args =  exchange.getIn().getBody(Object[].class);

        long id = (long) args[0];
        Holder<A> dataA = (Holder<A>) args[1];
        Holder<B> dataB = (Holder<B>) args[2];

        exchange.getOut().setBody(new Object[]{ dataA, dataB});

}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderInInterceptor.handleMessage(HolderInInterceptor.java:67)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:737)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2335)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream$1.run(HTTPConduit.java:2198)
```

I've read many similar problems descriped on web (ie.: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/java-lang-IndexOutOfBoundsException-in-cxf-producer-td468541.html) but without any success in resolving the problem.

In debug I get output message like:

```
Exchange[Message[null,null, A@xxxm B@yyy]]
```

I don't understand what the foolowing "null" values come from.
I've got only 2 outputs values (in Holders) according to wsdl file (and generated interface). I see also in debug console that in 'out' part of exchange body I have only 2 values set in ProcessResult()(idexed from 2 to 3), and size value of the 'out' part is set to '4' (not 2) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: The error is the same but the reason why it's appeared is different. In my case it problem with defining outputs in Camel Integration Framework. It was  described in some forums but I have not found the soultion already.

Comment: Problem solved: I didn't send holders in request messagem deleting following lines fixed the problem: ( Holder<A> dataA = (Holder<A>) args[1];
        Holder<B> dataB = (Holder<B>) args[2];). I'm creating new output holders and set new values for them,

Comment: The cause of such an exception is always different.  But the point of that Q&A is that you should almost never post to SO "I have an AIOBException".  You should post "why does `args` not have the things that it should have".